# Invalid grant issue with Google OAuth authentication in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, oauth, google-oauth

I'm developing a Qt application and I want to use Google authentication for it. I created a Google API as explained in the following link: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0/ but I have a problem with it. It doesn't work in many cases and I get ***ProtocolInvalidOperationError***(302) error for https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token request URL in 
*QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler::networkReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)*
method of Qt class.

Note that I override *QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler::networkReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)* to get this error, because it doesn't emit any signal in this case, and the return value for *reply->readAll()* is as below:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Malformed auth code."
}
```

My Login.cpp code is something as below:

```js
Login::Login() {
google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow;
google->setScope("email");
google->setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
google->setClientIdentifier(Utility::decrypt(encryptedClientId));
google->setAccessTokenUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
google->setClientIdentifierSharedKey(Utility::decrypt(encryptedClientSecret));

connect(google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser,
          &QDesktopServices::openUrl);

connect(google,&QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizationCallbackReceived,[=](const QVariantMap data){

        QString code(data["code"].toString());
        if(!code2.isEmpty())
        {
            const QUrl redirectUri= "http://localhost:56413/cb";
            QJsonObject postdata;
            postdata.insert("code",code);
            postdata.insert("client_id", Utility::decrypt(encryptedClientId));
            postdata.insert("client_secret", Utility::decrypt(encryptedClientSecret));
            postdata.insert("redirect_uri", redirectUri.toString());
            postdata.insert("grant_type","authorization_code");

           QString serviceURL = "oauth2/v4/token";
           NetworkManager::GetInstance()->Post(postdata,serviceURL,"https://www.googleapis.com/",[=](int statusCode,int resultnumber, QJsonObject obj){
               if (statusCode >= 200 &&
                   statusCode < 300)
               {
                   // it's ok, do nothing
               }
               else {
               //show error
               }
           });  
        }
    });
}

void Login::googleLoginButtonPressed() {
    int googlePort = 56413;
    if(replyHandler == nullptr)
        replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandlerArio(googlePort, this);
    google->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);

    QObject::connect(replyHandler, &QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler::tokensReceived, [=](const QVariantMap &map) {
        googleToken = map["id_token"].toString();
        connect(google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, [=]() {
            auto reply = google->get(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"));
            connect_reply = connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=]() {
                int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
                if (statusCode >= 200 &&
                    statusCode < 300)
                {
                    //NOW register or login the user with email

                    QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll().data());
                    email = jsonResponse.object().value("emails").toArray()[0].toObject().value("value").toString();
                    reply->deleteLater();
                }
                else {
                    //error
                }
            });
        });
    });

    google->grant();
}
```

what's the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same issue with Qt 5.9.1 on Windows

Answer (score 1):

We have posted a lengthy document describing [how to authenticate with Google SSO and Qt](https://appfluence.com/productivity/how-to-authenticate-qt-google-sso/) and this is one of the problems we discuss. I suspect the reason is that the login code returned by Google is URL-encoded, and Qt does not decode it automatically for you. So before you set your `replyHandler`, you need to invoke `setModifyParametersFunction` to decode it, in the middle of the flow.

```
google->setModifyParametersFunction([](QAbstractOAuth::Stage stage, QVariantMap* parameters) {
   // Percent-decode the "code" parameter so Google can match it
   if (stage == QAbstractOAuth::Stage::RequestingAccessToken) {
      QByteArray code = parameters->value("code").toByteArray();
      (*parameters)["code"] = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(code);
   }
});
```